# Intellisense autocompletion of expressions to watch in watch window or debug console

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, autocomplete, vscode-debugger

Is it possible while debugging, and a breakpoint has been hit, to autocomplete variables in the current scope in the Debug Console or the Watch Window?

An example gif is attached of where I would hope to get some auto-completion suggestions.

[image]

Essentially, on typing just `long`, I would like to autocomplete to work here so that it suggests `longish_variable_name` that I can then possibly tab complete.

VSCode has, by default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> mapped to triggering autocompletion suggestions, but this only seems to work in the editor window.

Answer (score 1):

Use the variable once in the debug window, and auto-complete will do the rest of the work for you ever after (given the variable name shouldn't be changed, or you need to use it in the debugger console again to get auto-completion suggestion.)

I have a test variable named `very_very_long_var` — but the debug window didn't suggest anything on the first go. It was presented once I used it the first time in that window.

[image: Debugger]

Comment: Yes. I did figure this out. But I was hoping to see a full fledged intelisense-based autocomplete capability.

Comment: C/C++ executes GDB, manages I/O, and projects in the debug window. The commands are remembered temporarily, so that they could be called later faster. IntelliSense is not designed to be used in debug window.

Comment: In this case, it need not even be intellisense based -- vim has autocompletion based on words used in the current open buffers -- no intelligence needed. I would be happy with something similar that is purely syntax driven and need not even be semantically driven.